# Sharepoint page not loading properly for some users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Most of the users (*except my team*) are not able to load our sharepoint site. They do have access but all the view is broken. This started 2 days back (without any change from my end) before which everything was working fine.

[image]

### MORE INFO:

1. Only our team (5 members) can view it correctly. Rest all get this broken page.
2. Deleted Cookies, Cache & Temp files for the effected users (Not resolved)
3. Added the website in Compatibility View Settings (Not resolved)
4. Tried changing the permission to 'Contribute' for those users (Not resolved)
5. Tried adding a new user to our Teams group today (just to check), but even he is getting this incorrect page
6. Tried adding a new user (who is not part of any group) in Admin group, still he is getting the same incorrect page
7. Our team use (IE8 & IE11) and there is no problem loading the pages for us, it is only other groups & new people added to the site
8. This site is on SharePoint 2010

Comment: Check whether CCS files loaded correctly for from F12 developer window > Resources

Comment: @vinayak-hegde: I don't have Resource / Network in IE8, where else can I check

Comment: When you say "6.Tried adding a new user (who is not part of any group) in Admin group, still he is getting the same incorrect page" do you mean you added the user to the site collection administrators, or that you added the user to a SharePoint group called "Admin"?

Comment: @Thriggle I added the person to a group called "Admin" where he has Full Control of the site.

Comment: @RoshanHyderRymbai have you checked the permissions assigned to the Style Library and Masterpage gallery at the root site of the site collection? Those libraries don't necessarily inherit permissions from the site itself.

Comment: @Thriggle Yes, all the users have access to Masterpage gallery. However, I didn't find Style Library, where is it located ?

Comment: You don't have access to Chrome Browser ? There you can check, whether your browser able to getting All the resources.. If not then there is Permission problem with Library where you have stored your CSS files